# The deadline for OAuth re-review is March 31st 2019 and may take some weeks

Tags: api, oauth

We have an app which uses OAuth to connect to mailboxes via IMAP to Gmail.

We have been advised that we need to re-verify our OAuth screen by March 31st and this may take some weeks. We have submitted the re-review but I wanted to know if the integration will break after March 31st if it is still pending review.

I've already tried to find support topics on this question but advised to come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have until May 15th to complete the verification process. If you are in the process of completing requirements, refer to this section of the FAQ: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#how-long